Is there a way to modify this Actual/360 post to incorporate rate changes at periods in the formula to arrive at the ending balance of any period?
I've been working with this post that goes back a few years [here][1]
[1]: Remaining Balance Formula for Actual/360 and Actual/Actual Accrual Methods.    In Mathematica, I've shown this to work and solve for d in loops.   I'd like to add to this by changing rates, such as in an Adjustable Rate Mortgage, and solve for d at each period the rate changes.  This cannot be brought down to a simple example for which I can provide code.  No effort of mine has come close, and I wondered if there were a way to introduce d[k] in the same manner that X[k] appears in the math?
Bruce
